# Why Does a Print Statement Execute Twice in a Python Multiprocessing Script?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm working on a simple script that utilizes the multiprocessing module. I have no experience with this module and I'm just trying to understand how to use it. I'm starting simple. However, I've encountered a puzzling behavior where the print statement in my script is being executed twice.

My understanding is that, as long as I'm running the script directly, the code under `if __main__` should run. And, the entire script should run procedurally. I was expecting the print statement to run only once prior to the `if` block. Why is it being executed multiple times? I typically don't structure my code using this pattern, so I'm wondering if there's behavior associated with using `if __main__` that I might not be aware of. It's just a normal `if` statement like any other."

I'm not sure what's going on here. Can someone please provide some insights into why this might be happening? Thank you!
I'm running python 3.11.3 from Anacaonda-Spyder 5.4.3

```
import multiprocessing

print("TEST TEST TEST")

def square(x):
    return x * x

if __name__ == '__main__':
     numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
     with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
         results = pool.map(square, numbers) 
     print(results)
```

Results:

```
TEST TEST TEST
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

TEST TEST TEST
TEST TEST TEST
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Context and start methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods). One print is coming from your top-level processes, and two from your worker processes.

When using the *spawn* method, multiprocessing may import your module to access the `square` function. If you don't want module level code such as this print statement to be executed, it needs to go inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard.

If you set the start method to *fork*, then you should only get one print here:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')
    ...
```

But don't rely on that - instead fix your module so that the import doesn't have side-effects.

Comment: Thanks! So, once I have the results from the `with` context manager, if I want to work with it, all of that processing must be contained within the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard, right? It seems that outside of this guard, I can only define functions. Is that correct?

Comment: @Sushi Well, the processing can (and probably should) be contained in other functions too.